# Jenkins hosted in AWS instance unable to connect to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

Just need some help as I am new in this system and the previous guy did not provide much documentation.

Currently the jenkins server is hosted in Aws in an instance but this instance only have a private ip address thus the only way of routing to the internet would be through another instance of ours that is hosted in Aws too but in another private ip address. But as we are new to this system, we accidentally stop and start all our instances. Thus now our jenkins are unable to fetch from our github.

*To Note* the public ip has changed but private ip has not changed

TLDR
-how to allow our instance 1(jenkins) ssh to instance 2(public) that will route out to the internet so as to fetch the code back to instance 1?

Any solution to this? as currently we tried these few method
- create a new job with same configuration *worried if file corrupted*
- make sure the plugin version is align with the previous working one
- tried to git config --global but there is no config file in jenkins or not under .ssh/config

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the NAT gateway ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: @RamKamath i follow what was mention for this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIGEmrhiuXo) and the configuration is the same so i am currently not sure if my jenkins instance is even trying to access the internet or is it blocked internally as my jenkin is an image hosted on a docker container

Comment: How do you spin the Jenkins docker image? Do you expose ports ? `docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' <YOUR IMAGE ID>` can you execute this command on the VM that runs your . Jenkins docker image . ?

Comment: Check if your host is connected to internet first. Execute some curl command `curl https://www.google.com` maybe.

Comment: You need to check whole network chain to see what stopped working. We don't know how you configured your instances. You either have access point as public instance or NAT gateway/instance. Configuration for one of them is changed.